# QDataStream not working as well and return error with reusing

Tags: qt, qt5, qdatastream

I am storing some data in QDataStream and immediately taking the data

```
bool M_FILEMANAGER::readFromDataFile(QString& fileName,RADARBEAMPATTERN *radbeam)
{
// for reading from file sequence .....
QFile fin(m_folderPath +"/"+ fileName);
if (fin.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QDataStream in(&fin);
    in.device()->startTransaction();
    in >> radbeam->nPoints;
    qDebug()<<"nPoints : "<<radbeam->nPoints;
    fin.close();
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

it works fine for one use but when i reuse this function i get error 
segmentation fault.
thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please read [ask], review the [tour] and provide a **[mcve]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Strange use of `QIODevice::startTransaction()`. Did you mean to use `QDataStream:startTransaction()`? You shouldn't need that at all, but if you meant to use it to check for "valid" (complete) data in the file, do it [properly](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#using-read-transactions) (although this is typically used with async devices like sockets):

```
int nPoints;  // temp variable to hold data, assuming radbeam->nPoints is an int
QDataStream in(&fin);
in.startTransaction();
in >> nPoints;
if (in.commitTransaction() && radbeam != nullptr)
    radbeam->nPoints = nPoints;
fin.close();
```

2) Segfault is most likely due to `radbeam` pointer (eg. being null), but possibly if you're trying to read corrupted data directly into the member variable `nPoints`.  Impossible to determine cause w/out MCVE.

Comment: sorry what is w/out MCVE ?

Comment: @clevertiger, sorry, MCVE = [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And "w/out" is short for "without."  :)